# Integrate Dojo Build into Grails Build?

Tags: grails, build, dojo

I understand dojo's build system, but I'm rather new to Grails.  Does anyone know how, or have a resource for, integrating dojo's JS build into Grails?  I'd like to be able to use the JS sources during development, and then switch to the built version of JS for production.

So far, I am envisioning just having the dojo-src directory in js dir, and using that during development.  Then, when I want to deploy to prod, I'll manually run a dojo build and output it also in the /js dir.

(I'm planning to us a request parameter to tell the app which js to use, compressed or src).

Is there another, better, way I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a whole lot about grails, but I think you are on the right path.  I use a query parameter to set the configuration to use, but i store the configuration in the session, so that I don't need it on every page.

Take a look at my answer to this: 
[How do I use uncompressed files in Dojo 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020267/how-do-i-use-uncompressed-files-in-dojo-1-7/11034664#11034664)

From what I have read on Grails, it uses ant for building.  This is an ant script to build.  I don't know how to integrate it into the gant convention for building a war.

```
<java fork="true" dir="${dojo.build.util.dir}/buildscripts"
classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">

<classpath>
    <pathelement location="${dojo.build.util.dir}/shrinksafe/js.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${dojo.build.util.dir}/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar"/>
</classpath>

<arg value="build.js"/>
<arg value="version=${version}"/>
<arg value="profileFile=../../profile.js"/>
<arg value="action=release"/>
<arg value="releaseDir=../../../"/>
<arg value="releaseName=${dojo.releaseName}" />
<arg value="optimize=shrinksafe"/>
<arg value="cssOptimize=comments.keepLines"/>
</java>
```