# Searching for strings in a Shell script

Tags: shell, dojo

Using a shell script, I am trying to search for a string in a file and then returning that value in a variable so I can manipulate it in the shell script.

I am using a dojo build script and this script needs to define a version number for dojo.
By default the build script defines the version number as 0.0.0.dev. What I am trying to do, is search in my original dojo files for the definition of dojo.version and then using that value to manually set the version number of my compiled build to that value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the version by passing it as a parameter to the build script.

This is a windows example using the bat file

```
build.bat profileFile=my.profile.js action=release releaseDir=../../../release/
 releaseName=rel copyTests=false optimize=comments 
 cssOptimize=comments version=THE_VERSION_YOU_WANT
```

My answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092237/integrate-dojo-build-into-grails-build) shows an ANT build that overrides the version.

Comment: Thanks for your response, although I do not want to simply define a static version number, I want to read what version I am using directly from the file and then use that in my release.

Answer (score 0):

Since you flag as `shell`, ill make it bash; This is the key regexp to look for : `dojo\.version[\ \t]*=[\ \t]*{`

In short; following works out box at the two versions i tested:

```
# grep -A20 includes comments, excluding these by following
flattenedlines=$(line=$(grep -nRe "dojo\.version[\ \t]*=[\ \t]*{" *); head -n `echo 20+$(echo $line|cut -d ":" -f2)|bc` $(echo $line|cut -d ":" -f1) | tail -n 21| grep -v "\/\/")
echo $flattenedlines | sed "s/'/\"/" | sed 's/.*major[\ \t]*:[\ \t]*\([0-9]*\).*minor[\ \t]*:[\ \t]*\([0-9]*\).*patch[\ \t]*:[\ \t]*\([0-9]*\).*flag[\ \t]*:[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1 - \2 - \3 - \4/'
## result ## :"nMajor - nMinor - nPatch - szFlag"
```

There are two different versions, which i personally have looked through.. Version 1.4.0 and 1.7.2 uses two different files (and i believe this is rather consistent at least from 1.2 up with 1.6 minors being the turning point)

Go through dojo/_base/ directory with this command, which should give you a file and line number to start with, along with the subset of lines after the expression found. This is based on fact that a *non-compressed sdk* is being used.

```
dojobase="/var/www/dojotoolkit/dojo"

#command will return similar to following
# for 1.4.2 : "_loader/bootstrap.js:208:    dojo.version = {"
# for 1.7.2 : "kernel.js:97:    dojo.version = {"
pushd $dojobase/dojo/_base
lines=$(grep -A20 -Re "dojo\.version[\ \t]*=[\ \t]*{" *)
```

Know, this is the text to parse

```
    dojo.version = {
            // undefined
            // number of lines
            // with comments
            major: 1, minor: 7, patch: 2, flag: "",
            revision: rev ? +rev[0] : NaN,
            toString: function(){
                    var v = dojo.version;
                    return v.major + "." + v.minor + "." + v.patch + v.flag + " (" + v.revision + ")";      // String
            }
    };
```

Making the `$lines` buffer look like so:

```
dojo.version = { _loader/bootstrap.js- // summary: _loader/bootstrap.js- // version number of dojo _loader/bootstrap.js- // major: Integer _loader/bootstrap.js- // Major version. If total version is "1.2.0beta1", will be 1 _loader/bootstrap.js- // minor: Integer _loader/bootstrap.js- // Minor version. If total version is "1.2.0beta1", will be 2 _loader/bootstrap.js- // patch: Integer _loader/bootstrap.js- // Patch version. If total version is "1.2.0beta1", will be 0 _loader/bootstrap.js- // flag: String _loader/bootstrap.js- // Descriptor flag. If total version is "1.2.0beta1", will be "beta1" _loader/bootstrap.js- // revision: Number _loader/bootstrap.js- // The SVN rev from which dojo was pulled _loader/bootstrap.js- major: 1, minor: 4, patch: 0, flag: "dev", _loader/bootstrap.js- revision: rev ? +rev[0] : NaN, _loader/bootstrap.js- toString: function(){ _loader/bootstrap.js- with(d.version){ _loader/bootstrap.js- return major + "." + minor + "." + patch + flag + " (" + revision + ")"; // String _loader/bootstrap.js- } _loader/bootstrap.js- } _loader/bootstrap.js- }
```

Using sed, this is one line by another, done like this:

```
  major=$(echo $lines | sed 's/.*major[\ ]*:[^0-9]*\([0-9]\)*,.*/\1/')
  minor=$(echo $lines | sed 's/.*minor[\ ]*:[^0-9]*\([0-9]\)*,.*/\1/')
  patch=$(echo $lines | sed 's/.*patch[\ ]*:[^0-9]*\([0-9]\)*,.*/\1/')
```